# Feedback Framework for Cocoa

Tags: cocoa, frameworks, feedback

I tried `FeedbackReporter.framework` from [vafer.org](http://vafer.org/projects/feedbackreporter/) but it doesn't want to work. :-/
So any suggestions for great Cocoa feedback frameworks?

Comment: The most recent version is from less than two weeks ago, so it's not like it's abandonware. What do you mean by “it doesn't want to work”?

Comment: Pablo, I am the author of FeedbackReporter. I am wondering what problems you've run into. Why didn't you contact me?

Comment: Every time I want to call a [[FRFeedbackReporter sharedReporter] sendFeedback] my app is killed. What's making me wonder is: [FRFeedbackReporter sharedReporter != nil] :-/

Comment: Please check the docs. It's [[FRFeedbackReporter sharedReporter] reportFeedback]; Have you compared your code with the examples provided?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this one from Jon Rentzsch:

http://github.com/rentzsch/jrfeedbackprovider/tree

It's a good start.

Comment: The project doesn't seem to build on latest Mac OSX - and they have disabled raising issues ( presumably because there are so many)  Would recommend looking at alternatives

Answer (score 2):

There is also OpenFeedback at http://code.google.com/p/appcaster/. This also includes Appcaster which you could find useful. I personally ended up going with JRFeedback.

Answer (score 1):

[UKCrashReporter](http://zathras.de/angelweb/blog-ukcrashreporter-oh-three.htm) handles detecting and submitting crash logs (e.g. at app startup) and submitting feedback from within the app. I've been very happy with it.

Answer (score 1):

I've never used it, but apparently the author of [Feedback Reporter](http://vafer.org/projects/feedbackreporter/) monitors Stack Overflow and will try to help if you bother explain your problem.

Comment: Every time I want to call a [[FRFeedbackReporter sharedReporter] sendFeedback] my app is killed. What's making me wonder is: [FRFeedbackReporter sharedReporter != nil] :-/